# How can I enable logging to Xcode->Device manually on deployed iOS apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I'm trying to capture some log that's leading to a crash of the app. I can't reproduce this issue other than on production (deployed on app store). I tried adding NSLog to watch it in Xcode devices when the issue happens but NSLog gets called pretty frequently (once a second), uses too much CPU and the phone becomes hot. So I want to only enable logging when the device is plugged into XCode. Is there any way I can manually enable logging?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to enable the logging for only debug builds and disable them for prod builds?

Comment: No, I want to enable manually in prod build per user basis. or a way to do frequent NSLogs (once a second) without burdening the CPU.